# Caffe Compilation on Windows - Compiles Successfully But 0xc000007b Error

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cuda, caffe

I have followed the steps at [this URL](https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/build-caffe-in-windows-with-visual-studio-2013-cuda-6-5-opencv-2-4-9/) to compile Caffe for windows. The compilation succeeds but I am unable to run the generated EXE file. Also, when I downloaded the Git branch, there was already a caffe.exe file listed there. When I tried to run the precompiled file, I also got this error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application". This is the same error I get on my compiled binary.

Please help me. I am running Windows 7 x64. I suspect the problem could be creeping in somewhere that maybe since I have like 32 bit MinGW or something maybe it is trying to use the 32 bit libraries?

Right now, I have my configuration set to build x64 bit. I feel like one of the problems could be that maybe the CUDA is trying to build 32 or something? I just don't know what's causing this.. Even stranger, why am I not able to run the precompiled caffe.exe that I found when I downloaded this.. (I get the exact same error, that makes me feel like it isn't my compilation process.. there is something else going on).

Thank you for your help

OK - I ran the dependency walker. I identified the following issues:

**Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.**

**Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.**

LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL

LIBGFORTRAN-3.DLL

are x86 but the rest of them are x64. Where can I get the 64 bit DLLs from?

Also, 
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL

DCOMP.DLL

IESHIMS.DLL

Are listed as being not found (the system cannot find the file specified).

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency error for Windows applications--in others words, you're probably missing a DLL file. Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to help find out which DLL files you're missing.